# Q: Tensorflow: tf.random_crop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used the `tf.random_crop()` to crop 56*56 in my patch (80, 80).`patch = tf.random_crop(patch, [56, 56, 3])` I get the error like follow:

```
Caused by op u'random_crop', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 26, in main
    low_res_batch, high_res_batch = batch_queue_for_training(TRAINING_DATA_PATH)
  File "/data/code/super_resolution/anima2x/src/data_inputs.py", line 26, in batch_queue_for_training
    high_res_patch = tf.random_crop(patch, [LABEL_SIZE, LABEL_SIZE, NUM_CHENNELS])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 322, in random_crop
    return array_ops.slice(value, offset, size, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 484, in slice
    return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2868, in _slice
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected size[0] in [0, 38], but got 56
     [[Node: random_crop = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Reverse, random_crop/mod, random_crop/size)]]
     [[Node: case/If_1/ResizeArea/images/_67 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_150_case/If_1/ResizeArea/images", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I don't know why the expected size must be in [0, some_num smaller than 56], Could anyone help to solve it?

Comment: could you print the shape of patch, just to make sure it is the expected (80, 80, 3)?

Comment: @Yao Zhang, Thanks for your comment, Yes I make sure that the patch is (80,80,3) I have use the get_shape() to get the tensors' shape. Maybe it is the fault of my dataset(the val dataset of ImageNet), I change to another dataset it seem fine. But I don't know the reason of the error.

Comment: Looks like the original dataset may have images of size 38.